# What is the math behind the min function in Geogebra?

Tags: min, geogebra

So as of yet, I am not profficient in programming.

I am writing a paper in mathematics and obtained different results from the GeoGebra min function and algebraical methods.
I am sure that the algebraical methods are correct, but I really want to know why the min function was faulty.

The result from the algebra was an interval between 1010 and 1011.

From GeoGebra I got a single point as a solution (1010.15898).

If you could explain to me why GeoGebra ommits all of these other solutions, I would be very thankful.

I would also appreciate if someone could direct me to the math behind the function, so I could include it in my paper and discuss its' relevance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

GeoGebra is using a modification of the (local) optimization algorithm given in Richard Brent, Algorithms For Minimization Without Derivatives, Prentice-Hall, Inc. 1973.

See [the source code](https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/d4b39be828a9e3823d473671abdfc787259bbcef/common/src/main/java/org/geogebra/common/kernel/optimization/ExtremumFinder.java#L151) for more information.